# How to dynamically track the the values of form fields?

Tags: google-tag-manager, google-analytics-4

I want to track the field values after submitting a form in gtm. I tried creating dataLayer variable, like
"gtm.element.3.value". But here '3' which is the index value of an input field is static. I want it dynamic so that I don't have to create multiple variables. Do we have to create multiple dataLayer variables of each index value, like gtm.element.0.value, gtm.element.1.value, gtm.element.2.value, etc. ?

Basically I want to make this process dynamic instead of adding the index value statically. Is it possible in GTM?

Answer (score 0):

That completely depends on the format in which your form values are pushed to the dataLayer. Normally, we would ask front-end to push meaningfully named values to the DL to then use in GTM.

From where you're at, you can just make one custom JS variable and parse your elements as you wish, adding the dynamicity you require. In production, however, it's not a good practice to hack things like that. If they add or remove a field in your form, the indexes will shift and your data will suddenly change without notice. This can easily lead to wrong conclusions on the data consumption side.